# ArToolkit examples with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, artoolkit

i've been trying to open and compile ArToolkit examples from AndroidStudioProjects in ArToolkit5 with Android Studio but i have some errors like following.
[image: Errors]

I've latest version of Android Studio. I'm new to ArToolkit and Android Studio any help will appreciated.

Comment: With which Version of the JDK do you build it? (FIle->project Structure->SDK Location->JDK Location) Try to use a recent Oracle JDK 1.7

Comment: i've used jdk1.8.0_25.

Comment: Did using JDK 1.7 solve this particular issue?

Answer (score 2):

In gradle change the below code

```
android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

to

```
compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import ArToolKit Eclipse project in Android studio, from File>New>Import Project.. And do follow steps..